# Android Studio doesn't generate signed apk after update to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have faced some troubles with uploading release version to fabric(crashlytics) after generating release build in Build->Generate Signed Apk. 
After moving app-release.apk into Fabric window I see following error: ***"The provided APK can't be distributed
because it is unsigned."***

[Fabric error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sofee.png)

What I'm doing wrong? Keystore and its password didn't change.

Comment: Have you zip-aligned the apk? Also disable Instant Run before signing your apk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday.

I had to make sure the checkboxes for signature versions where both checked. These both are unchecked by default.

[image]

Comment: Yes, surprisingly, I had this too happen after upgrade;

Comment: Thank you very much, Ruben. You saved my day.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer when possible :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but even after checking two check boxes for signature version, signed apk doesn't appear. :(

Comment: just app-release.apk and and app-debug.apk

Comment: Okay, I realized, that it's possible to zipalign app-release.apk, and then Google play it accepts.

Comment: I cannot select it :/

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this:-**v2SigningEnabled false**  in your build.gradle.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
        keyPassword "password"
        v2SigningEnabled false
      }
    }
  }
```

After then select 
[image]